# Surrounding window frame disappeared after Ubuntu release upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell

Surrounding window frame disappeared after Ubuntu release upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS so window maximize, minimize and close icons are not present anymore:

[image]

Note: Few months ago I switched from Unity to Gnome. Now I don't remember what exactly I installed for that, but everything was working fine.

Also, Alt+Tab and Alt+F2 don't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this switching to Gnome with no effects session and changing Theme to Default.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed the wrong graphics driver for nvidia.  Make sure you have the latest (correct) driver.